# Google in app billing (i already own the object)

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, billing

In my app I can only purchase once the app, but when i retry to do it i get that the item is bought. I Exactly obtain: "In-app billing error: Unable to buy item, Error response: 7:Item Already Owned" I know that i have to restart the purchase of my acount, because I have tried to reinstall my app but nothing happens.

How can i reset this purchase? And I need an easy guide to do real tests because google´s guide is really bad. Thank you very much!

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=google+testing+in+app+billing -> http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have not published your application on Play-Store,kindly just `change package name or version of application`, it will automatically reset your purchases.

I hope it will be helpful !!

Comment: @user2800899: I'm glad to help.kindly accept it as answer so that it can be helpful to other developers who may face the similar issue in future.